# Session Timeout Warning in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session, iis

I have an mvc 4 application where I need to show an alert warning when the session reaches its timeout.

I have seen various articles online that explain to do this in asp.net, but I'm looking for a way out to do it in MVC.

P.S: We don't have forms authentication in our application. Can I still achieve it without forms authentication/authorization.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I think below links may answer your question.

[How do I warn the user that their web session is about to time out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740230/how-do-i-warn-the-user-that-their-web-session-is-about-to-time-out)

http://fairwaytech.com/2012/01/handling-session-timeout-gracefully/