# Detect Session Timeout and display popup when session is about to clear in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have to display a popup window when my session is about to clear in .net MVC.

[example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Detect-Session-Timeout-and-redirect-to-Login-Page-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

I want same thing implement in MVC. What should I do???

Here I have try some code:

This is the controller page(error comes that ClientScript doesnot exist):

```
   Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Web.Config");
        SessionStateSection section = (SessionStateSection)config.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
        int timeout = (int)section.Timeout.TotalMinutes * 1000 * 60;
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"SessionAlert", "SessionExpireAlert(" + timeout + ");", true);
```

Here is my script in view(that I call from controller):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SessionExpireAlert(timeout) {
    var seconds = timeout / 1000;
    document.getElementsByName("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
    document.getElementsByName("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        seconds--;
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
        document.getElementById("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        //Show Popup before 20 seconds of timeout.
        $find("mpeTimeout").show();
    }, timeout - 20 * 1000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = "Expired.aspx";
    }, timeout);
};
function ResetSession() {
    //Redirect to refresh Session.
    window.location = window.location.href;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do this.Page object can be invoked in web forms since the server side code is tightly coupled but you cannot do this using mvc

Comment: why???how to do in mvc..i think must be any way to do this..if you have any solution tell me..

Comment: You can use JQuery javascript library and trigger an ajax request and in the success handler you can do your required operations.

Comment: can you write down a code for doing this operation

Comment: Yeah before that ..I would like to know if the above controllers code is present in action method or constructor of the Controller?

Answer (score 3):

Get the timeout for the users session first:

```
int sessionTimeout = HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout;
DateTime timeoutDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(sessionTimeout);
```

You can pass that to your view through your Model or ViewBag and use a javascript timer to pop up an alert. (Since session is refreshed on every request, this will be an accurate timeout).

View:

```
@{
    int milliseconds = (int)ViewBag.sessionTimeout * 60 * 1000;
}
setTimeout(function(){alert("SessionPop!");}, @milliseconds.ToString());
```

But since sessions are refreshed on hitting controller actions you might want to provide real time support (especially if your app is going to be used in multiple tabs or heavily utilizes AJAX calls). You could look into using SignalR to update in real time when the new session timeout will expire to the user.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, MVC controller doesn't require `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` when passing a script content into view. You can just register the script block using `ViewBag`/`ViewData` and `Html.Raw` like this one, just ensure that the controller returns view with `ViewBag`/`ViewData` included:

```
public ActionResult WarnTimeout()
{
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/Web.Config");
    SessionStateSection section = (SessionStateSection)config.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");
    int timeout = (int)section.Timeout.TotalMinutes * 1000 * 60;
    ViewBag.Script = "\r\n<script type='text/javascript'>\r\nSessionExpireAlert(" + timeout + ");\r\n</script>\r\n");

    return View();
}

// View (use Html.Raw to include script tag into view)
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Script)

<script type="text/javascript">
function SessionExpireAlert(timeout) {
    var seconds = timeout / 1000;
    document.getElementsByName("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
    document.getElementsByName("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        seconds--;
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
        document.getElementById("secondsIdle").innerHTML = seconds;
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        //Show Popup before 20 seconds of timeout.
        $find("mpeTimeout").show();
    }, timeout - 20 * 1000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        // when using MVC, you may use Url.Action instead of providing ASPX relative path
        window.location = "@Url.Action("Expired", "Controller")";
    }, timeout);
};
function ResetSession() {
    //Redirect to refresh Session.
    window.location = window.location.href;
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, jQuery ajax call (`$.ajax({ ... })`) with certain data provided then setting desired alert box operation inside `success` part may be used.

Any suggestions welcome.

Reference to similar problem:

[How do I warn the user that their web session is about to time out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740230/how-do-i-warn-the-user-that-their-web-session-is-about-to-time-out)

Comment: I suppose Html.Raw would only register your script into the view but it would not trigger the script. To do to so you have to explicitly trigger on page load if the user is using a get postback.Your alternative solution is much better to deal with